# How to fix 'Failed to fetch Debian Jessie-updates' issue on Docker?

Tags: php, docker, debian

My docker was working fine. I reset the disk image of Docker and then when I run the 'docker-compose up -d' command.

I started to get "Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

" error.

My DockerFile is

```
    FROM php:7.1.16-apache

   #install all the system dependencies and enable PHP modules
   RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
  libicu-dev \
  libpq-dev \
  libmcrypt-dev \
  git \
  zip \
  unzip \
  python \
  python-setuptools \
  libmemcached-dev \
&& pecl install memcached \
&& rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
&& docker-php-ext-configure pdo_mysql --with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd \
&& docker-php-ext-install \
  intl \
  mbstring \
  mcrypt \
  pcntl \
  pdo_mysql \
  pdo_pgsql \
  pgsql \
  zip \
  opcache \
&& docker-php-ext-enable memcached \
&& pecl install -o -f redis \
&&  rm -rf /tmp/pear \
&&  docker-php-ext-enable redis


   RUN pecl install xdebug

   RUN easy_install supervisor

   #RUN echo_supervisord_conf > /etc/supervisord.conf

   ADD supervisord.conf /etc/supervisord.conf

   ADD php.ini $PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini

   #RUN echo "zend_extension=/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/xdebug.so" to php.ini

   VOLUME /var/www/html

   WORKDIR /var/www/html

   #install composer
   RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin/ --filename=composer

   #set our application folder as an environment variable
   ENV APP_HOME /var/www/html

   #change uid and gid of apache to docker user uid/gid
   RUN usermod -u 1000 www-data && groupmod -g 1000 www-data

   #change the web_root to laravel /var/www/html/public folder
   RUN sed -i -e "s/html/html\/public/g" /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

   # enable apache module rewrite
   RUN a2enmod rewrite

   #copy source files and run composer
   #COPY . $APP_HOME

   # install all PHP dependencies
   #RUN composer install --no-interaction

   #change ownership of our applications
   RUN chown -R www-data:www-data $APP_HOME

   ADD startup.sh /root/

   RUN chmod 755 /root/startup.sh

   CMD ["/root/startup.sh"]
```

How can I fix the issue?

Answer (score 9):

Add

`RUN sed -i '/jessie-updates/d' /etc/apt/sources.list`

before your line

`RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \ ......`

Comment: it worked for me! thank you very much Santik!

Comment: worked for me too. thank you Santik!

Comment: @santik any ides why it worked?

Comment: @rail_engine libraries were removed from the default source, so this solution just uses another sources.

Comment: It doesnt work for me. Any idea?