# Dockerfile - debian Jessie 404: packages not found

Tags: python, linux, docker, ubuntu, debian

I'm trying to set up a docker container on Debian 9.8, but I keep getting the following error when I run `docker-compose up -d`:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
```

Which then causes the process to be cut short.

I have the following Dockerfile (shortened for readability) with 2 calls to `apt-get update` that I have modified with suggestions [from](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/508724/failed-to-fetch-jessie-backports-repository) [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55361762/apt-get-update-fails-with-404-in-a-previously-working-build) [pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55387506/how-to-fix-failed-to-fetch-debian-jessie-updates-issue-on-docker) to no avail:

```
RUN echo "deb [check-valid-until=no] http://archive.debian.org/debian jessie main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jessie.list
RUN sed -i '/deb http:\/\/deb.debian.org\/debian jessie-updates main/d' /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN apt-get -o Acquire::Check-Valid-Until=false update
RUN sed -i '/jessie-updates/d' /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN apt-get update
```

I also removed any references I could find to jessie in `/etc/apt/sources/list`. What am I missing?

**EDIT** I didn't realise there were multipls dockerfiles in the project, so I edited all of them one by one. That said, is there a way of centralizing the process?

Comment: Try removing the `apt-get update` statements from dockerfile and see what is happening.

Comment: @demouser123 ok so there are in fact 10 dockerfiles across the app and each one calls apt-get update at some point, is there a way to centralise a solution?

Comment: It's not clear which line is throwing the error. Can you simplify and isolate your problem down to a [mcve]?

Comment: The edited question is very different from the original question. It would probably be best to close this as a duplicate and open a new question with enough detail on your project layout and multiple Dockerfiles that advice can be given. Creating your own base image is a common practice but difficult to advise without seeing each Dockerfile.

Answer (score 2):

I ran the following without issue:

```
$ cat df.jessie-updates
FROM python:3.5.2
RUN sed -i '/jessie-updates/d' /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN apt-get update \
 && apt-get install -y git

$ DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0 docker build -f df.jessie-updates -t test-jessie-updates .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  23.04kB
Step 1/3 : FROM python:3.5.2
 ---> 432d0c6d4d9a
Step 2/3 : RUN sed -i '/jessie-updates/d' /etc/apt/sources.list
 ---> Running in f2a056c4c0f2
Removing intermediate container f2a056c4c0f2
 ---> 07fff7724882
Step 3/3 : RUN apt-get update  && apt-get install -y git
 ---> Running in a862679899c0
Ign http://deb.debian.org jessie InRelease
Get:1 http://deb.debian.org jessie Release.gpg [2420 B]
Get:2 http://deb.debian.org jessie Release [148 kB]
Get:3 http://security.debian.org jessie/updates InRelease [44.9 kB]
Get:4 http://deb.debian.org jessie/main amd64 Packages [9098 kB]
Get:5 http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages [825 kB]
Fetched 10.1 MB in 8s (1130 kB/s)
Reading package lists...
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Suggested packages:
  gettext-base git-daemon-run git-daemon-sysvinit git-doc git-el git-email
  git-gui gitk gitweb git-arch git-cvs git-mediawiki git-svn
Recommended packages:
  less rsync
The following packages will be upgraded:
  git
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 161 not upgraded.
Need to get 3709 kB of archives.
After this operation, 371 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates/main git amd64 1:2.1.4-2.1+deb8u7 [3709 kB]
debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
Fetched 3709 kB in 2s (1557 kB/s)
(Reading database ... 21602 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../git_1%3a2.1.4-2.1+deb8u7_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking git (1:2.1.4-2.1+deb8u7) over (1:2.1.4-2.1+deb8u2) ...
Setting up git (1:2.1.4-2.1+deb8u7) ...
Removing intermediate container a862679899c0
 ---> fc422b5b9188
Successfully built fc422b5b9188
Successfully tagged test-jessie-updates
```

This is [based off of your second link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55362112/596285) which you described as not working. If you have a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) including a minimal and complete dockerfile, and the full output from running a build, that may help us debug further.

Answer (score 1):

Any one who might be facing this issue jessie-update fails or jessie-backports fail, this solution worked for me.

```
 RUN echo 'deb http://archive.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jessie-backports.list
 RUN sed -i '/jessie-updates/d' /etc/apt/sources.list
 RUN apt-get -o Acquire::Check-Valid-Until=false update`
```