How to reproduce my server's PHP environment in Docker?
I have a server running PHP 5.5.38 and I want to make a Docker container to run the code locally so I can test my changes before pushing them to production over FTP.
Unfortunately the code doesn't run in an unmodified php:5.5-apache image. Instead, I just get all sorts of errors and warnings. I'm guessing that's because the image is missing PHP extensions expected by the codebase.
I can access the machine and I have the output of phpinfo() at /phpinfo.php, so I think it should be possible to produce a Dockerfile that can launch the code in an environment close enough to the original for development purposes; I just don't know how.
Things I've already discovered:

The php:5.5-apache image refers to unmaintained package repositories and apt-get update doesn't work out of the box. I got it working by adding the following lines above RUN apt-get update:
RUN sed -i '/jessie/d' /etc/apt/sources.list \
  && echo "deb http://archive.debian.org/debian jessie main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list


I can install dependencies required by some PHP extensions using apt-get install, however I don't know how to determine which packages I need, nor how to install a specific version, should that be required.

I can configure some extensions using docker-php-ext-configure, but I don't know how to determine which flags are needed, nor which extensions need this kind of configuration. Perhaps the configure command from phpinfo can help? I copy-pasted it at the end of this post.

I can install PHP extensions using docker-php-ext-install, but I don't know what to do when faced with error messages concerning unfound files and packages such as the error message I copy-pasted below my Dockerfile near the end of this post.

I can enable PHP extensions using docker-php-ext-enable, but I don't know how to determine which extensions require this.


My (broken) Dockerfile after initial attempts with the help of ChatGPT:
FROM php:5.5-apache

# Remove unmaintained `jessie-updates` and `jessie/updates`, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55387506/how-to-fix-failed-to-fetch-debian-jessie-updates-issue-on-docker
RUN sed -i '/jessie/d' /etc/apt/sources.list \
  && echo "deb http://archive.debian.org/debian jessie main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list

# RUN apt update
RUN apt-get update

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get install -y --force-yes libbz2-dev \
  libc-client-dev \
  libcurl4-openssl-dev \
  libfreetype6-dev \
  libgmp-dev \
  libicu-dev \
  libjpeg-dev \
  libkrb5-dev \
  libmcrypt-dev \
  libpng-dev \
  libreadline-dev \
  libtidy-dev \
  libvpx-dev \
  libwebp-dev \
  libxpm-dev \
  libxml2-dev \
  libzip-dev \
  libenchant-dev \
  unixodbc-dev \
  libpq-dev \
  libsnmp-dev \
  libldap2-dev \
  libsasl2-dev \
  libssl-dev
  # libxsl-dev

# Ensure that the shared libraries are properly registered in the system's dynamic linker cache
RUN ldconfig

# Remove packages, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13436356/configure-error-utf8-mime2text-has-new-signature-but-u8t-canonical-is-missi
RUN rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Link gmp.h to the correct location, see https://superuser.com/questions/802025/configure-error-unable-to-locate-gmp-h
RUN ln -s /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/gmp.h /usr/include/gmp.h

# Configure PHP extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr --with-jpeg-dir=/usr
RUN docker-php-ext-configure ldap --with-libdir=lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --with-ldap --with-ldap-sasl
RUN docker-php-ext-configure imap --with-imap --with-imap-ssl=/usr/local --with-kerberos
RUN docker-php-ext-configure pdo_odbc --with-pdo-odbc=unixODBC,/usr
RUN docker-php-ext-configure intl --with-icu-dir=/usr

# Install PHP extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install bcmath
RUN docker-php-ext-install bz2
RUN docker-php-ext-install calendar
RUN docker-php-ext-install ctype
RUN docker-php-ext-install curl
RUN docker-php-ext-install exif
RUN docker-php-ext-install ftp
RUN docker-php-ext-install gd
RUN docker-php-ext-install gettext
RUN docker-php-ext-install gmp
RUN docker-php-ext-install iconv
RUN docker-php-ext-install imap
RUN docker-php-ext-install ldap
RUN docker-php-ext-install mbstring
RUN docker-php-ext-install mcrypt
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli
RUN docker-php-ext-install openssl
RUN docker-php-ext-install pcntl
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_pgsql
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_sqlite
RUN docker-php-ext-install pgsql
RUN docker-php-ext-install posix
RUN docker-php-ext-install readline
RUN docker-php-ext-install shmop
RUN docker-php-ext-install soap
RUN docker-php-ext-install sockets
RUN docker-php-ext-install sqlite3
RUN docker-php-ext-install sysvmsg
RUN docker-php-ext-install sysvsem
RUN docker-php-ext-install sysvshm
RUN docker-php-ext-install tokenizer
RUN docker-php-ext-install xml
RUN docker-php-ext-install xmlrpc
RUN docker-php-ext-install xmlwriter
RUN docker-php-ext-install xsl
RUN docker-php-ext-install zip

RUN docker-php-ext-enable \
  bcmath \
  json \
  mbregex \
  mhash

# Create the public_html directory as it appears on the production server
RUN mkdir -p /home/portage/public_html

# Change Apache's document root to /home/portage/public_html
RUN sed -i 's|/var/www/html|/home/portage/public_html|g' /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

# Add Apache Directory permissions for /home/portage/public_html
RUN echo '<Directory /home/portage/public_html>\n    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks\n    AllowOverride All\n    Require all granted\n</Directory>' >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

# Enable mod_rewrite and mod_litespeed (if compatible)
RUN a2enmod rewrite

# Overwrite public_html/.htaccess with .htaccess.local to avoid redirections to the production server
COPY ./.htaccess.local /home/portage/public_html/.htaccess

# Expose port 80 (Apache default)
EXPOSE 80

The Dockerfile above fails with configure: error: Cannot find OpenSSL's <evp.h>
The configure command from phpinfo:
'./configure' '--build=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' '--host=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' '--target=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' '--program-prefix=' '--prefix=/opt/alt/php55' '--exec-prefix=/opt/alt/php55' '--bindir=/opt/alt/php55/usr/bin' '--sbindir=/opt/alt/php55/usr/sbin' '--sysconfdir=/opt/alt/php55/etc' '--datadir=/opt/alt/php55/usr/share' '--includedir=/opt/alt/php55/usr/include' '--libdir=/opt/alt/php55/usr/lib64' '--libexecdir=/opt/alt/php55/usr/libexec' '--localstatedir=/var' '--sharedstatedir=/usr/com' '--mandir=/opt/alt/php55/usr/share/man' '--infodir=/opt/alt/php55/usr/share/info' '--cache-file=../config.cache' '--with-libdir=lib64' '--with-config-file-path=/opt/alt/php55/etc' '--with-config-file-scan-dir=/opt/alt/php55/link/conf' '--disable-debug' '--disable-opcache' '--enable-calendar' '--enable-dbx=shared' '--enable-exif' '--enable-ftp' '--enable-gd-native-ttf' '--enable-shmop' '--enable-sockets=shared' '--enable-xml' '--with-bz2' '--with-curl=/opt/alt/curlssl11/usr' '--with-exec-dir=/usr/bin' '--with-freetype-dir=/usr' '--with-gettext' '--with-gmp' '--with-iconv' '--with-jpeg-dir=/usr' '--with-layout=GNU' '--with-libxml-dir=/opt/alt/libxml2/usr' '--with-mcrypt=shared,/usr' '--with-mhash' '--with-openssl-dir=/opt/alt/openssl11' '--with-openssl=/opt/alt/openssl11' '--with-pic' '--with-png-dir=/usr' '--with-readline' '--with-tidy=shared,/usr' '--with-vpx-dir=/usr' '--with-webp=/opt/alt/libwebp' '--with-xpm-dir=/usr' '--with-zlib' '--with-zlib-dir=/usr' '--without-gdbm' '--without-pear' '--with-mssql=shared,/opt/alt/freetds11/usr' '--with-pcre-regex=/opt/alt/pcre/usr' '--with-pdo-dblib=shared,/opt/alt/freetds11/usr' '--with-t1lib=/opt/alt/t1lib/usr' '--with-kerberos=/opt/alt/krb5/usr' '--with-interbase=shared,/usr' '--with-pdo-firebird=shared,/usr' '--with-litespeed' '--enable-bcmath=shared' '--enable-dba=shared' '--with-db4=/usr' '--enable-dom=shared' '--enable-fileinfo=shared' '--enable-intl=shared' '--enable-json=shared' '--enable-mbregex' '--enable-mbstring=shared' '--enable-pcntl' '--enable-pdo=shared' '--enable-phar=shared' '--enable-posix=shared' '--enable-soap=shared' '--enable-sysvmsg=shared' '--enable-sysvshm=shared' '--enable-sysvsem=shared' '--enable-wddx=shared' '--enable-xmlreader=shared' '--enable-xmlwriter=shared' '--enable-zip=shared' '--with-enchant=shared,/usr' '--with-gd=shared' '--with-icu-dir=/opt/alt/libicu57/usr' '--with-pdo-odbc=shared,unixODBC,/usr' '--with-pdo-sqlite=shared,/opt/alt/sqlite/usr' '--with-pspell=shared' '--with-recode=shared,/usr' '--with-sqlite3=/opt/alt/sqlite/usr' '--with-unixODBC=shared,/usr' '--with-xmlrpc=shared' '--with-ldap=shared,/opt/alt/openldap11' '--with-ldap-sasl' '--with-pdo-pgsql=shared,/usr' '--with-pgsql=shared,/usr' '--with-imap=shared,/opt/alt/libc-client11' '--with-imap-ssl=/opt/alt/openssl11' '--with-snmp=shared,/opt/alt/net-snmp11/usr' '--with-xsl=shared,/usr'

